# Integrability of $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^{1+\frac{1}{x}}-a-\frac{b}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math, taylor-expansion

This is from an MCQ contest.

> For all  $x\geq 1$ let
>   $$f(x)=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x} \right)^{1+\dfrac{1}{x}}-a-\dfrac{b}{x}$$ 
>   note that  $$f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{=}}(1-a)+\dfrac{1-b}{x}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ Then we have :
>
> 1. if $a=1$ and $b\neq 1$ then $f$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty($
> 2. if $a=1$ and $b=1$ then $f$ is not integrable on $[1,+\infty($
> 3. if $b=1$  then $f$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty($
> 4. if $a=1$ and $b=1$ then $f$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty($

My Thoughts :

1. False

If $a=1$ and $b\neq 1$ then
$$f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{=}}\dfrac{1-b}{x}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ but $f$ isn't integrable on $[1,+\infty($ since

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1-b}{x}dx=(1-b)\int_{1}^{+\infty} dx=+\infty$$

2. False

if $a=1$ and $b=1$ then
$$f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{=}}o\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
but f is integrable on $[1,+\infty($ since 
$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx=1$ then $f$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty ($

3.False  if $b=1$ then
$$f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{=}}(1-a)+o\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
but $f$ isnt integrable on $[1,+\infty($ since 
$\int_{1}^{+\infty}(1-a)dx=+\infty$ then $f$ isnt integrable on $[1,+\infty ($
 4.True if $a=1$ and $b=1$ then 
$$f(x)\mathrel{\underset{_+\infty}{=}}o\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
since  $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx=1$ then $f$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty ($

- Is My proof correct
- Is there any kind of reasoning one may use during a contest, when a quick answer is needed